# Why am I not earning weapon commendations?

Tags: halo-4

I don't get why I'm not earning weapon commendations. I don't have a Gold account, but I'm still a Silver at least. Do I need gold to get them or what am I doing wrong?

I am connected to the Internet, I just tried using wargames(local) and I didn't receive anything like I would in Halo Reach.